# Lottery contract has infinite gas issue

Tags: infinite-loop, solidity

I'm getting this error "Gas costs:
Gas requirement of function Lottery.getPlayers is infinite:
If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed.
Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage
(this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)" Also I want to add a way to deposit extra tokens from the same wallet as the contract is deployed.
```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

````
contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public  players;
    constructor() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }
    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager,"only manager has access");
        _;
    }
    function balanceInPool()public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether,"the amount should be more than 0.1 ether");
        players.push(msg.sender);
   }
    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty,now,players)));
    }
    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        address payable winner = payable(players[index]);
        players = new address[](0);
        winner.transfer(address(this).balance);
     }

    function getPlayers()public view returns(address[] memory){
    return players;
    }

        
}
```
````

Comment: 1) Based on the `now` keyword, I'm guessing you're using Solidity v0.6.x or older. Can you specify the exact version you're using? ... 2) After copy-pasting the code to Remix IDE, compiling under Solidity v0.6.12, I was able to sucessfuly call the `getPlayers()` function - not getting the same error as you. Please provide steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PetrHejda Thank you for the response. I am using v0.6.0.  just so you know I'm new to Solidity. but this issue happened when i was trying to compile it in Remix IDE as it sits now. I will try to use v0.6.12, and i will let you know. I appreciate it!